# The Minkowski inequality for fractional order?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in C^\infty(\bar I)$ be given where $I=(0,1)$. Define
$$
t(\alpha):=\left(\int_I\int_I \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^\alpha}{|x-y|^{1+s\alpha}}\right)^{\frac1\alpha}
$$
where $1<\alpha<2$, $0<s<1$ is fixed. Note the $t(\alpha)$ above defines the fractional order sobolev seminorm. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space), roll down for the section "Sobolev spaces with non-integer $k$".

We know that for $L^p$ space, if $p<q$ then $\|u\|_{L^p(I)}\leq \|u\|_{L^q(I)}$ by using holder inequality. So I am wondering whether similar properties hold for sobolev space with non-integer $k$.(of course, for integer case it is again a Holder inequality)

That is, I am wondering for $1<\alpha_1<\alpha_2<2$, do we have
$$
t(\alpha_1)\leq Ct(\alpha_2)
$$
hold, where $C$ is a constant does not depends on $u$. Just like what we usually have for $L^p$ norm. However, I tried to prove it by using minkowski inequality or sth like holder, but I can't do it... I think the domain $I=(0,1)$ would be important and I also tried to use Jensen inequality, but no lucky...

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $t(\alpha,s)$ what you define as $t(\alpha)$. If $s_{1}-\frac{1}
{\alpha_{1}}=s_{2}-\frac{1}{\alpha_{2}}$ with $s_{1}\geq s_{2}$ (or
equivalently $\alpha_{2}\geq\alpha_{1}$), then you should have
$$
t(\alpha_{2},s_{2})\leq ct(\alpha_{1},s_{1}).
$$
There is a paper of Simon that you can find online at
http://math.unice.fr/\symbol{126}jsimon/pubs/Simon-E4.pdf

Take a look at Theorem 10.

If you don't change $s$ as you are trying to do, then there are
counterexamples in Stein's book "Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions". For $s<1/\alpha$, the
function
$$
f(x)=|x|^{s-1/\alpha}(\log1/|x|)^{-\delta}
$$
for $|x|<1/2$ extended smoothly and with compact support to all of
$\mathbb{R}$ should satisfy
$$
t(\alpha,s)<\infty
$$
if and only if $\delta\alpha>1$. It's an exercise in the book.

Comment: Why it is a counterexample?

Comment: I changed my question a bit. But it shouldn't matter

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can't look at the reference while I am on a train. (too hard to use cell on MSE). I will have a look after I get back to home. It is just a bit surprising for me that the nighter order of $L^p$ norm does not control the lower order $L^p$ norm, especially the domain is bounded.

Comment: it shows that for $\alpha >1/\delta$ the seminorm is finite while for $\alpha \le 1/\delta$ it is not, so you cannot expect an inclusion similar to $L^2 \subset L^1$. The difference I think is that here you are dealing with difference quotients and so the regularity of the functions comes into play, while for $L^p$ it is just how functions grow, so the problems are quite different.